# Tag & Rename Mac OS X equivalent

Tags: osx, music, metadata-editor

I'm looking for a Mac OS X free clone of the [Tag & Rename](http://www.softpointer.com/tr.htm) Windows software.

The features I need are:

- Batch ID3v2 tag editing for various music file formats (MP3, M4A,
  FLAC, ...)
- Batch renaming of music files based on their ID3v2 tags

My MacBook Air is running Mac OS X Mavericks.

Any directions would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14958/mp3-classification-with-cddb/18943#18943

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer iTunes where it not only allows batch editing, but changes the file name and directory structure based on the Tagging information

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Media Rage](http://www.chaoticsoftware.com/ProductPages/MediaRage.html). While visually not the most attractive OSX app around, it does the things you're looking for:

> A collection of powerful tools for media enthusiasts with a Macintosh
>   using Mac OS X. Media Rage can read and write information stored in
>   MP3, AAC/MP4, FLAC, AIFF, WAVE, BWF, and Ogg Vorbis audio files as
>   well as EXIF (read only) tags in digital images. Media Rage can assist
>   you in cataloging, organizing, sorting, and updating thousands of
>   audio files with ease.

Answer (score 1):

Its not free but [Jaikoz](http://www.jthink.net/jaikoz) meets both of your requirements, in addition it amongst other things it can automatically identify songs. Jaikoz is  a stable product that was originally launched in 2008 and is still actively developed, the latest release was only last week.

Disclaimer:I am the Jaikoz developer

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a lot of need for software like this, but since I'm iTunes-averse, I've appreciated using **[Tagger](http://bilalh.github.io/projects/tagger/)**.

[image: Tagger]

OP's features:

- [image: Yes] **Yes!** Batch ID3v2 tag editing for various music file formats (MP3, M4A, FLAC, ...)
- [image: Yes] **Yes!** Batch renaming of music files based on their ID3v2 tags

Additional features of interest:

- FOSS under Apache 2.0 license
- supports artwork, folder manipulation, much more...