# MP3 classification with CDDB

Tags: osx, mp3, id3, classification

I am currently using [TagScanner](http://www.xdlab.ru/en/) to reorder, renamed and take ID3 tags for my mp3 collection under my Windows 7 computer.

I am looking to buy a MacBook and I am wondering what alternative to TagScanner exists for MacOS system?

The I like the feature to rename and recreate directories and to have all the CDDB metadata (track title, album, artist, release year etc...) and the most interesting feature: it is free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using **[EasyTag](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/EasyTAG)** for similar tasks on Linux. According to Wikipedia, this software is also available for MacOS and Windows.

[image: EasyTag Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot of [EasyTag](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/EasyTAG) (source: Wikipedia; click image for larger variant)</sup>

This software should match your requirements (at least those you've explicitly mentioned):

- it's free (even open source: [GNU GPL](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License) licensed)
- You can edit tags, it even fills them automatically via a "user-definable mask" by directory/filename structure
- files can be directly renamed (see upper-right part in the screenshot)
- it supports CDDB (I've never used that part, but Wikipedia says so ;)

[EasyTag](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/EasyTAG) runs stable (I'm using it for years already, though only occasionally; I never saw it crash), fast, and is pretty flexible. In short: fun to work with. Just give it a try, it's free :)

Answer (score 0):

[MP3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/mac-osx.html) can be executed with [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) (if that’s an option).

Copy/paste from website:

> **Main features:**
>
> - Batch Tag Editing Write ID3v1.1, ID3v2.3, ID3v2.4, MP4, WMA, APEv2 Tags and Vorbis Comments to multiple files at once.
> - Support for Cover Art Download and add album covers to your files and make your library even more shiny.
> - Import from Amazon, discogs, freedb, MusicBrainz Save typing and import tags from online databases like Amazon, discogs, freedb, MusicBrainz, and more.
> - Replace characters or words Replace strings in tags and filenames (with support for Regular Expressions).
> - Create Playlists automatically Create and manage playlists automatically while editing.
> - Rename files from tags Rename files based on the tag information and import tags from filenames.
> - Export to HTML, RTF, CSV Generate nice reports and lists of your collection based on user-defined templates.
> - Full Unicode Support User-interface and tagging are fully Unicode compliant.
> - Besides these main features Mp3tag offers a variety of other functions and features ranging ranging from batch export of embedded album covers, over support for iTunes-specific tags like media type or TV Show settings, to combining multiple actions into groups that can be applied with a single mouse click.

I use this software under Windows and does please my needs.